# rails ruby double pipe session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm trying to make the following work:

1) If I'm a user, I get signed out when I delete my account.

2) If I'm an admin, I stay signed in when I delete other user's account.

It works when I set the current_user method as

```
  def current_user
    @current ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

but when I set it as

```
  def current_user
    User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

it gives me this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#destroy
Couldn't find User with 'id'=30
```

I don't understand why "@current ||=" makes it work.

```
application_controller.rb

def require_signin
  unless current_user
    session[:intended_url] = request.url
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "This page requires signin"
  end
end

def require_admin
  unless current_user_admin?
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Unauthorized Access"
  end
end

def current_user_admin?
  current_user && current_user.admin?
end

def current_user
  @current ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end


user_controller.rb 

def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user?(@user) || current_user_admin?
        redirect_to root_path, alert: "Unauthorized Access"
    end     
    @user.destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil unless current_user_admin?
    redirect_to players_path, alert: "'#{@user.name}' was deleted"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||=` operator means "set this variable if its not already set".

When you delete the account that you are currently signed in as, you remove the `User` from the database, however the `session[:user_id]` is still set to the now deleted `User`'s ID.

Attempting to call `User#find` with a user ID which has been deleted will result in an `ActiveRecord` error.

The reason why this does *not* happen when the `||=` operator is present is because the `@current` variable is *already* set therefore the `User#find` is never called.

```
# this will only try to call User#find if the @current variable is not already set
@current ||= User.find(session[:user_id])

# this will always attempt to call User#find
# if session[:user_id] is set to a deleted user's ID it will raise an error
@current = User.find(session[:user_id])
```

Comment: when does the @current value get reset?

Comment: This is the offending line: `session[:user_id] = nil unless current_user_admin?`. When you call `current_user_admin?`, it calls `current_user` which tries to reset the `@current` variable. If you delete a `User` you should always clear it out of the session. Perhaps try `session[:user_id] = nil if session[:id] == params[:id]` This will clear out the session if the ID is equal to the ID of the user you just deleted.

Comment: is there any way to make the second current_user method work?

Comment: If you ensure that `session[:user_id]` never contains an invalid user ID then the second `current_user` method will work. It's still recommended to use the `||=` operator because it is way more performant (you'll only every run the `User#find` query once per request cycle.

Comment: Happy to help! :)